# File used by another process ; PDF.JS ; iText

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, pdf.js

I'm using PDF.JS to display document that I upload to the server in canvas element using PDF.JS that's working perfectely. That time i'm using iTextSharp to digitally sign the document. When i try to sign the document an Exception is throwed (Exception.IO.Exception) The file is already used by another process. here is my Code for uploding the file :)

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Upload()
    {
        string fileName = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (string item in Request.Files)
            {
                var fileContent = Request.Files[item];
                if(fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var inputStream = fileContent.InputStream;
                    fileName = fileContent.FileName;
                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFolder"), fileName);
                    using (fileContent.InputStream)
                    {
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            await inputStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("Upload failed");
        }
        return Json(fileName);
    }
```

There's how i display PDF in canvas

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btn2").click(function () {
    var url = document.getElementById("document-to-sign").getAttribute("required-document");
    if (url != "" && url != null) {
        var pdfDoc = null,
            pageNum = 1,
            pageRendering = false,
            pageNumPending = null,
            scale = 1.5,
            canvas = document.getElementById('document-to-sign'),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function renderPage(num) {
            pageRendering = true;

            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function (page) {
                var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: ctx,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

                renderTask.promise.then(function () {
                    pageRendering = false;
                    if (pageNumPending !== null) {

                        renderPage(pageNumPending);
                        pageNumPending = null;
                    }
                });
            });

            document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
        }

        function queueRenderPage(num) {
            if (pageRendering) {
                pageNumPending = num;
            } else {
                renderPage(num);
            }
        }

        function onPrevPage() {
            if (pageNum <= 1) {
                return;
            }
            pageNum--;
            queueRenderPage(pageNum);
        }
        document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

        function onNextPage() {
            if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
                return;
            }
            pageNum++;
            queueRenderPage(pageNum);
        }
        document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

        PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
            pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
            document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
            renderPage(pageNum);
        });
        PDFJS.disableStream = true;
        $("#document-to-sign").removeAttr("required-document");
    }
});
```

I finally that's how i'm signing the document (Adding the empty field to sign)

```
public static void AddField(string src, 
                                Double x1X, Double x1Y, Double x2X, Double x2Y, int page, 
                                string User)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            using (PdfStamper s = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(src, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(s.Writer);
                field.FieldName = "Signature de " + User;
                field.SetWidget(new Rectangle(Convert.ToSingle(x1X), Convert.ToSingle(x1Y), Convert.ToSingle(x2X), Convert.ToSingle(x2Y)), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_PUSH);
                field.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;
                s.AddAnnotation(field, page);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Fatal(e.ToString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I'm stacked in this line

```
using (PdfStamper s = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(src, FileMode.Open)))
```

**EDIT:**

I'm just adding the siging field in this step. Signing the document will be the next task, in console application i'm singing the document with a self-certificate. 
Upload the document, and adding the signing field and signing it will be further :)
Sorry for the confussion.

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You are adding a signature annotation. You are **not** signing the document. If you show the result to your customer and if your customer knows what he wants, you will get fired. I suggest that you read a manual on digital signatures before you continue.

Comment: As for your reported problem: you are accessing *the same file* from two different processes. That's not possible. You need to do this sequentially, and you need to release the file as soon as one of the processes is done processing.

Comment: I know that i'm not signing the file i'm just adding the signing field ,and signing it will be a little bit further. and to do it sequentially it's not possible. upload it, and signing it, will be in two different views.

Comment: OK, that wasn't what you were saying in your question, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found what i'm missing in reading the file

refer to this 
[Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617883/cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process)
i was passing the url of the file instead of reading the all bytes from stream

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);


PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath))
```